# How to get three table data in one in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have three different tables and different models. The tables are State Office, City Office, Hometown Office. I want to show the data of the office that the user will select between these three offices. There is a column in the user table called office_id. I'm brand new to Laravel so I don't know how. Would you please tell me how to do this?

I have already added some code to my User Model

```
public function stateoffice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(State::class, 'id', 'office_id');
}

public function cityoffice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CityOffice::class, 'id', 'office_id');
}

public function hometownoffice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(HometownOffice::class, 'id', 'office_id');
}
```

This is my controller code

```
 public function AllUser(){
    $data['user'] = User::all();
    $data['stateoffice'] = StateOffice::all();
    $data['cityoffice'] = CityOffice::all();
    $data['hometownoffice'] = HometownOffice::all();
    return view('admin.all-user', $data);
}
```

But I'm stuck in View how can I show it.

```
<thead>
    <th>Office Name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($user as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>@if($data->office_id == NULL)
            <span>no data found</span>
            @else
            {{$data->office->office_name}}
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Do you know about **eager loading**? `USER::with('hometownoffice', 'cityoffice', 'stateoffice')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

The `User` model has no property called "office", at least it is not shown in your example, so `$data->office` cannot work since `$data` is an instance of `User` in your foreach-loop (you should rename that btw).

You have to use `stateoffice()`, `cityoffice()` or `hometownoffice()`.